# CSS Hidden elements with :odd pseudo - selector

Tags: css, grid

The task is to create auto - adjusting css - grid with 3 main requirements:

1. absolutely javascript - free
2. with table - layout behavior (cells in row equally vertically aligned relative to baseline)  and may have different heights.
3. Some of cells may be hidden from view by different css rules. And grid must count on that and make appropriate reflow to fill empty cells by visible blocks.

Here the example model:

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
li {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float:left;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1st block<br>toll<br>content</li>
  <li class="hidden">short<br>2nd block</li>
  <li class="green">3rd block</li>
  <li class="hidden">4d block</li>
  <li>5th column</li>
  <li>6th block</li>
</ul>
```

Here, we have green block stacked to left border instead of replacing hidden second block to the right of first toll content block, where we get empty space. 
For aught I know the problem is that :odd pseudo - selector  include hidden elements.

Do we have by now any usable way to consider hidden elements in reflowing?

P.S. Sorry for terrible language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the CSS `flex`box model to layout a tabular structure. The key here is the `flex-basis` property on the items. Making it equal to the width i.e. 50% in this case, forces a two-column layout. Also required here is the `flex-wrap: wrap` property.

***See this snippet:***

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0; padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 75%;
  }

.green {
  background: green;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1st block<br>toll<br>content</li>
  <li class="hidden">short<br>2nd block</li>
  <li class="green">3rd block</li>
  <li class="hidden">4d block</li>
  <li>5th column</li>
  <li>6th block</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:odd` selector will not care for the visibility of the item...

Since you're using a class for hidden elements, you could clear the float based on the existence (or not) of that `.hidden` class, for example:

```
li:not(.hidden) + li:not(.hidden) {
   clear:left;
}
```

Would clear the float only when it has two immediated followed visible items...

See:

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
li {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float:left;
}
li:not(.hidden) + li:not(.hidden) {
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1st block<br>toll<br>content</li>
  <li class="hidden">short<br>2nd block</li>
  <li class="green">3rd block</li>
  <li class="hidden">4d block</li>
  <li>5th column</li>
  <li>6th block</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe i had't clearly enough express the exact target structure we must achieve. In your solution, 5th block stacked to right border under 3rd block, but in accordance to 2 - column grid it must be stacked to left border under 1st block, and the 6th block next to him.